# Which board game released in the 90's involved medieval combat?

Tags: identify-this-game

In the game, you could have castles and fortresses. There were ballistae and catapults and little sets that could be purchased to build upon your original set. The game had a rulebook and turn-based gameplay. Some units rolled special dice to determine actions' outcome.

What was this game called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely referring to Weapons & Warriors. Here is [Board James](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S22FFetltbE) playing it. The [rulebook](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/2132/weaponswarriorsrules-pdf) can be found here.

The game had several [expansions](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=boardgame&q=Weapons+%26+warriors&B1=Go). It contained cannons and ballista. You rolled dice to move your soldiers forward, which allowed you to move your firing pieces forward or fire your weapons.

- Weapons & Warriors: Castle Siege Game (1994)
- Weapons & Warriors: Pirate Battle (1996)
- Weapons & Warriors: Power Catapult Set (1994)
- Weapons & Warriors: Star Fort (1994)
- Weapons & Warriors - Lashout Launcher (1994)
- Weapons & Warriors: Cavalry Attack Set (1994)
- Weapons & Warriors: Weapon Pack 2 (1995)
- Weapons & Warriors Castle Storm / Pirate Clash Game (1997)